# How to configure pom.xml that dependency from produced jar was loaded when I add this jar as dependency?

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml

I have a maven project(common project). I exctracted part of this project(separated project) in standalone jar. I move all dependency needed for separated project in it `pom.xml` These dependency don't need in common project.

Now I deleted exctracted part of common project and delete unused in common project  dependency and add dependency for separated project to `pom.xml` of common project. I got a problem that classes from deleted dependency is not found. But these classes use only in separated project.

I tryed to return dependency in common `pom.xml` and I have a succees.

But it is bad. How to make that dependency from jar was loaded?

Comment: If you are using eclipse try to delete pom.xml and generete it once again

Comment: I use eclipse but I build in cmd